# How to add custom components to the new Email template builder in Salesforce sales/service cloud

Tags: apex, lightning, email, template, component

I am trying out the new Email template builder in Salesforce service cloud (winter 21). Here you can drag standard components to the email canvas and configure them. I would like to have some components here that for example list the last purchased products. I (sort of) know how to build components but have no clue how I would include these in the components I can select in the Email template builder. Who can help me on my way?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish this you would need to be able to set a target in the LWC *.js-meta.xml file for the custom component. I was curious about this as well and did some digging. As of the time of this answer (10/19/2020) I was not able to locate a target for this purpose, suggesting that it is not possible to create custom components for the Email Template Builder at this time. I assume the target will eventually be something like: lightning__EmailTemplate.

On a side note, Salesforce has been hard at work to come up with functionality for Lightning Email Templates, to the point that the EmailTemplate object does not behave as other standard objects (try using it as a lookup field for example). It's speculated that this is because of forthcoming functionality, including such things as related object merge fields, which are currently not really available in Lightning Email Templates. I suspect we are going to see a steady stream of Email Template (Builder) functionality being introduced over the next 1-2 years.

I know it's not the answer you were looking for, but alas, sometimes we have to be patient!